# How to Unmarshaller SOAP UI Values in JAVA Class uisng JAXBElement

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

I am trying to Unmarshaller the SOAP UI values in java class. Please find the example below:

```
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "UserList")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<UserListResponse> UserListRequest(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<UserListRequest> request) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Enters into UserList()");

          // create an unmarshaller
              JAXBContext context = 
                           JAXBContext.newInstance(UserListRequest.class);//Here i am providing the class name of request parameter
              Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

              JAXBElement<UserListRequest> root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(
                        header), UserListRequest.class); //here I am struggling to unmarshal and I am not getting what is value needs to be passed in place "header"

                 UserListRequest list = root .getValue();

                }
            }
```

SOAP Request XML passing in SOAP UI as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prim="http://COM.SERVICES.WebServices/UserServices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <prim:UserList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <prim:XMLRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Header>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:MessageID>2</prim:MessageID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:CorrelationID>2</prim:CorrelationID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:SystemID>2</prim:SystemID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:RequestorID>2</prim:RequestorID>
            </prim:Header>
            <prim:Reference>C</prim:Reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Number>1120521877477751</prim:Number>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Usercount>51</prim:Usercount>
         </prim:XMLRequest>
      </prim:UserList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

can anyone please help to Unmarshaller `@RequestPayload JAXBElement<UserListRequest>` request in Java Class.

Answer (score 0):

The line that throws the error...

```
JAXBElement<UserListRequest> root =
    unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(header), UserListRequest.class)
```

The var header is not declared anywhere in your method.  Shouldn't you be initially 'unmarshall' or parse the passed-in 'request' var before trying to see what headers are passed in?

What's also worth noting is that your request from SoapUI has no headers.

```
<soapenv:Header/>
```

Indicates to me no header info has been passed in.

Comment: Yes, That's what i am saying that i am struggling to unmarshaller that. Looks like SOAP UI Request Param values are not binding to the request param due o that it's giving error and i guess  unmarshaller not required here. If you have any idea please help me that why soap ui request param values are not binding to the request object. @Chris Adams

Comment: You're trying to interrogate a variable (header) which hasn't been declared or initialized.  Header may be a property on the request object, but you cannot access request.header by sumply typing header.  The variable you are passing in is called request.  Suggest you use the debugger to see what is in the request object.  So, set a breakpoint on the first line of the method (System.out.println("Enters into UserList()");) and then look at the request object.